# Why can't we write integrals in a way analogous to sums, without adding a differential form : $\int_{x=a}^b f(x)$ instead of $\int_a^b f(x)dx$?

Tags: integration, notation

It is my understanding that there is no mathematical significance to the "differential element" $dx$ at the end of an integral. Why hasn't the same convention as for sums with the sigma symbol been adopted ($\int_{x=a}^b f(x)$ instead of $\int_a^b f(x)dx$)? It seems clearer and more logical.

Edit: I understand that when using Lebesgue integrals the measure has to be indicated, but could this simpler notation at least work for integrals over sub-sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Edit: I know that integrals are not the same as sums, but I think it would make sense to use similar notations. Also, there are striking similarities between properties of sums/series and properties of integrals: for instance, asymptotic comparisons, or convolution for functions vs Cauchy products for series.

Comment: I would say for integration on $\mathbb{R}$ you might get away with it, but when it comes to measure theory notation of the form $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ is useful.

Comment: The differential $\mathrm dx$ does have a significance; the expression $f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ represents the area of the infinitesimally thin rectangles with length $f(x)$ and breadth $\mathrm dx$; you can see the significance of it when you make a variable substitution $u=\varphi(x)$ and the differential element becomes $\mathrm du=\varphi'(x)\,\mathrm dx$ and **not just** $\mathrm du=\mathrm dx$; I think the equivalence of definite integrals with Riemann sums should give you a geometric understanding of why the $\mathrm dx$ is important. (sums are 1-D, integrals are 2-D or above).

Comment: Prasun Biswas, whilst this can serve as a mental image, it seems that $dx$ still doesn't really have any **mathematical** meaning, does it ?

Comment: At the end of the day, it is a matter of notation. Each author has its preferred way to denote integrals. In the literature, variants such as $\int_a^b f$, $\int f$ (meaning $f$ is integrated over its whole domain) and $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ all appear. Note that it is very useful to use $dx$ as it explicits the variable with respect to which we are integrating, so we can define a function at the same time we are integrating it (for instance, $\int 2f(x) dx$ is clearly the integral of $g(x):=2f(x)$ but you do not have to define $g$ before writing this integral as such).

Comment: gpr1, I understand that, but "my" proposed notation also explicits the variable. I was wondering why this notation is seemingly not used at all even though it seems so clear.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Your explanation is inaccurate. The intuition that $\mathrm{d}x$ represents an infinitesimal area is just that: an intuition. It is not rigorous and it does not actually go in accordance with how the Riemann integral is defined. Mr. Jackie is right when he says the notation has no significance, at least in this particular context.

Comment: Because it's not a sum of $f(x)$; it's a sum of the product $f(x)dx$.

Comment: @Paul Again, that is inaccurate. See my comment. The $\mathrm{d}x$, at least in the context of real analysis, does not represent any mathematical object.

Comment: I have read sometimes that $dx$ has a mathematical meaning as a "differential form" and other times that it does not and is just a notation. I tend to believe the former, because indeed differential forms are not involved in the definition of the Riemann integral.

Comment: Physicist would complain that the integrals would get the wrong units. For example, $s = \int_a^b v \, dt$, where $s$ is distance, $v$ is velocity and $t$ is time, wouldn't look right without the $dt$.

Comment: @MrJackie yes, it does have meaning as a differential form, but it is not as cut and dry and simple as that. Read my answer for more details.

Comment: @HansLundmark This is true, but physicists are also not really working with the Riemann integral as defined in real analysis, they are working with integrals on manifolds. The notation just happens to look the same.

Comment: For what it's worth, I knew a professor who always wrote it this way. It was another reminder which one was the variable of integration when integrals would involve several parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notation is a matter of historical tradition and a matter of convenience, which is always dependent on context. This is true not only for the notation with integrals, but with the notation for sums as well, actually. For example, in elementary mathematics, we may denote $f(0) + f(1) + f(2)$ as $\sum_{n=0}^2f(n)$, but in higher mathematics, we are more inclined to using the notation $\sum_{n<3}f(n)$, which is more preferrable when working with ordinals in set-theory, or when doing discrete calculus. One may also write this as $\int{f\,\mathrm{d}c(x)}$ in the context of measure theory or time-scale calculus, where $c$ denotes the counting measure. The point is, depending on the application, we may want to modify a notation for the sake of convenience, but often, we also use a notation due to historical tradition.

In the context of real analysis, you are right: there genuinely is no significance to the symbol $\mathrm{d}x$. You can very much denote the Riemann integral of $f$ as $\int{f}$ if you want to. This is perfectly fine, and some authors actually do this. However, while this notation would be more convenient at the elementary level, it is desirable to include the symbol $\mathrm{d}x$ in higher mathematics for many reasons:

- In functional analysis, we would like to generalize the Riemann integral to the Riemann-Stieltjes integral with respect to an integrator $g$, which we denote as $\int{f\,\mathrm{d}g(x)}$. Here, the symbol definitely matters, because it denotes the integrator. Without it, one has no clue as to what the integrator actually is.
- Generalizing in a different direction, one may wish to generalize the Riemann integral to the Lebesgue integral, or even to the gauge integral, which has applications in physics. In this case, the symbol definitely matters, again, because it denotes which measure you are integrating with respect with. This actually is related to the Riemann-Stieltjes integral, and the full generalization is given by the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral.
- Yet another direction of generalization is when generalizing Riemann integration to arbitrary manifolds. In there, we use the idea of differential forms, and the symbol there is absolutely necessary. Just for reference, look at the generalized Stokes' theorem, which states $$\int_M\,\mathrm{d}\omega=\int_{\partial{M}}\omega.$$ It is not possible to express the theorem conveniently in any other way if we do away with the differential symbol.

So while it is true that the symbol is completely unnecessary when simply doing Riemann integration, we choose to keep it, because it lends itself more easily to transitioning to the notation for generalizations, which do absolutely need the symbol, and we do this, even if it does make it a little bit harder for beginners. Oh, and by the way, you are not even obligated to use the integral symbol to denote the integral of a function. For example, in fractional calculus, it is not uncommon for a differintegral operator to be denoted as $J$. Then the differintegral of order $s$ of $f$ is simply denoted $J^s[f]$. You would never think this refers to an integral based on the notation, but there is nothing stopping you from adopting this convention, as long as you make it clear in your writings. The Daniel integral uses a similar type of notation. Again: it all boils down to context.